# ImportError: cannot import name 'mylist' from 'mymodule'

Tags: python, module, multiprocessing

I have been trying to get a work around for my multiprocessing script, and I finally think I figured out something after about 8 hours of trying and failing. I want to import a script that contains a list that's in the same directory. In my main file there are 2 functions: the first is my `multiprocessing` function and the second is `main`. The list in the other file is the iterator for my multiprocessing `Pool`, but for some reason it says it cant find my list in my module.

My main file has:

```py
import mymodulename
import multiprocessing
def multiprocessingfunction(iteratornotactuallythename):
    #my code here
def main():
    pool = Pool(5)
    results = pool.map(multiprocessingfunction, mylist#the one that python cant seem to find)
```

I have tried to import it as `*`, import the single list like so: `from mymodulename import mylist`
and I have also tried to import it like so: `import mymodulename`.
When I try to import the single name it gives this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _mylist_ from mymodulename
```

When I try to import it normally or with the `*` I get this error:

```
"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute mylist
```

All of my files are in the same directory

My module file has:

```
def starting():
    mylist = [contentsoffile]
```

Just tried the traceback is:

```
  File "E:\a\nonargparseversion.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mymodule import arrang
ImportError: cannot import name 'arrang' from 'mymodule'
```

Answer (score 2):

`mylist` is a local variable to `starting()` function which means it invisiable to other modules after import, either put it in the global scope(same indentation with `def starting()`) or put `return mylist` in the end of the `starting()` and use `starting()`'s return value as `mylist` instead.

Comment: that did it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

```
import mymodulename
import multiprocessing
def multiprocessingfunction(iteratornotactuallythename):
    #my code here
def main():
    pool = Pool(5)
    results = pool.map(multiprocessingfunction, mymodulename.mylist)
```

Case 2:

```
from mymodulename import mylist
import multiprocessing
def multiprocessingfunction(iteratornotactuallythename):
#my code here
def main():
    pool = Pool(5)
    results = pool.map(multiprocessingfunction,mylist)
```

If you get error you should post the error taceback information. Not just a single sentence.

Comment: i gave you the traceback?